# Can you change the column order of a SQL statement being returned in Excel?

Tags: sql, excel

We are using a stored procedure to run a sales tax report in excel. The data pulls no problem, but is there an *easy* way to reorder the columns? Right now excel pulls Month, Date, Applied Month... and we need it to pull Month, Date, Customer, Contract...

I tried using "ORDER BY", but that doesn't actually change the column order, just how the data is sorted.

```
USE [Viewpoint];
```

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
/****** Object:  Stored Procedure dbo.brptARSalesTax    Script Date: 8/28/99 9:32:28 AM ******/
      --Drop proc brptARSalesTax
      ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[udbrptARSalesTax]
@ARCo [dbo].[bCompany] = 3, @BeginTaxCode [dbo].[bTaxCode] = '', @EndTaxCode [dbo].[bTaxCode] = 'zzzzzzzzz', @BeginMth [dbo].[bMonth] = '01/01/1950', @EndMth [dbo].[bMonth] = '12/1/2049', @NoTaxLines [dbo].[bYN] = 'N'
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS

```
  create table #Multilevel

    (Name   varchar (60)        NULL,
    ARCo    tinyint NULL,
    ARTrans int NULL,
    ARLine  int NULL,
    Mth smalldatetime   NULL,
    TransDate   Smalldatetime NULL,
    AppliedMth Smalldatetime NULL,
    Customer    int NULL,
    CustomerName varchar(30) NULL,
    Invoice varchar(10) NULL,
    CheckNo varchar(10) NULL,
    Description varchar (30) NULL,
    BaseTaxCode varchar (10) NULL,
    BaseTaxDesc varchar (30)    NULL,
    MultiLevel varchar (10) NULL,
    LocalTaxCode varchar (10) NULL,
    Contract varchar (10) NULL,
    ContractName varchar (60) NULL,
    LocalTaxDesc varchar (30) NULL,
    GLAcct varchar (20) NULL,
    TaxBasis decimal (12,2) NULL,
    TaxAmount decimal (12,2) NULL,
    TaxRate decimal (8,6) NULL,
    TaxLocalBasisTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
    TaxLocalAmountTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
    TaxBaseAmountTotal decimal(12,2) NULL,
    TaxBaseBasisTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
         DiscOffered decimal (12,2) NULL,
         TaxDisc decimal (12,2) NULL,
         TaxLocalDiscOffTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
         TaxLocalTaxDiscTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
         TaxBaseDiscOffTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
         TaxBaseTaxDiscTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
    Amount decimal (12,2) NULL,
    TotalAmount decimal (12,2) NULL)


  /* Creating Multilevel auxiliary table in order to select Customer Name */
  create table #Multilevel_Aux

    (Name   varchar (60)        NULL,
    ARCo    tinyint NULL,
    ARTrans int NULL,
    ARLine  int NULL,
    Mth smalldatetime   NULL,
    TransDate   Smalldatetime NULL,
    AppliedMth Smalldatetime NULL,
    Customer    int NULL,
    CustomerName varchar(30) NULL,
    Invoice varchar(10) NULL,
    CheckNo varchar(10) NULL,
    Description varchar (30) NULL,
    BaseTaxCode varchar (10) NULL,
    BaseTaxDesc varchar (30)    NULL,
    MultiLevel varchar (10) NULL,
    LocalTaxCode varchar (10) NULL,
    Contract varchar (10) NULL,
    ContractName varchar (60) NULL,
    LocalTaxDesc varchar (30) NULL,
    GLAcct varchar (20) NULL,
    TaxBasis decimal (12,2) NULL,
    TaxAmount decimal (12,2) NULL,
    TaxRate decimal (8,6) NULL,
    TaxLocalBasisTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
    TaxLocalAmountTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
    TaxBaseAmountTotal decimal(12,2) NULL,
    TaxBaseBasisTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
         DiscOffered decimal (12,2) NULL,
         TaxDisc decimal (12,2) NULL,
         TaxLocalDiscOffTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
         TaxLocalTaxDiscTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
         TaxBaseDiscOffTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
         TaxBaseTaxDiscTotal decimal (12,2) NULL,
    Amount decimal (12,2) NULL,
    TotalAmount decimal (12,2) NULL)


  create table #BaseRate

    (TaxGroup        tinyint          NULL,
    TaxCode         varchar (10)      NULL,
    OldBaseRate     Decimal(8,6)      NULL,
    NewBaseRate     Decimal(8,6)      NULL,
        EffectiveDate   smalldatetime   NULL,
          Description   varchar (30)    NULL,
    GLAcct      varchar(20) NULL,
    LocalTaxCode    varchar (10)    NULL)

  /* insert OldBaseRate and NewBaseRate Info */
  insert into #BaseRate
    (TaxGroup, TaxCode, OldBaseRate, NewBaseRate,EffectiveDate,Description,GLAcct,LocalTaxCode)

    SELECT b.TaxGroup,b.TaxCode,
          OldBaseRate=sum(case when b.MultiLevel='Y'  then x.OldRate else b.OldRate end),
          NewBaseRate=sum(case when  b.MultiLevel='Y' then x.NewRate else b.NewRate end),
          EffectiveDate=(case when b.MultiLevel='Y' then x.EffectiveDate else b.EffectiveDate end),
    Description=(case when b.MultiLevel='Y' then x.Description else b.Description end),
        x.GLAcct,LocalTaxCode = x.TaxCode
    FROM HQTX b with (nolock)
    Left Join HQTL a with (nolock) on a.TaxGroup=b.TaxGroup and a.TaxCode=b.TaxCode
    Left Join HQTX x with (nolock) on x.TaxGroup=a.TaxGroup and x.TaxCode=a.TaxLink

    GROUP BY
       b.TaxGroup, b.TaxCode,b.MultiLevel,b.EffectiveDate, x.EffectiveDate, b.Description,x.Description,x.GLAcct,x.TaxCode

  /* insert Multilevel Code Info */
  insert into #Multilevel
    (Name, ARCo,    ARTrans, ARLine, Mth,TransDate, AppliedMth, Customer, Invoice, CheckNo, Description, Contract, BaseTaxCode, BaseTaxDesc, 
    MultiLevel, LocalTaxCode, LocalTaxDesc, GLAcct, TaxBasis, TaxAmount,TaxRate,DiscOffered,TaxDisc,Amount)

     SELECT HQCO.Name,ARTL.ARCo, ARTL.ARTrans, ARTL.ARLine, ARTL.Mth,
          ARTH.TransDate, ARTH.AppliedMth, ARTH.Customer,
    ARTH.Invoice, ARTH.CheckNo, ARTH.Description, ARTH.Contract,
    BaseTaxCode=base.TaxCode,
    BaseTaxDesc=base.Description,
    MultiLevel=base.MultiLevel,
    LocalTaxCode=case base.MultiLevel when 'Y' then #BaseRate.LocalTaxCode  else #BaseRate.TaxCode end,
    LocalTaxDesc=case base.MultiLevel when 'Y' then #BaseRate.Description  end,
    GLAcct=case base.MultiLevel when 'Y' then #BaseRate.GLAcct else base.GLAcct end,
    ARTL.TaxBasis,
    ARTL.TaxAmount,
    /*
    TaxRate=case  base.MultiLevel when 'Y'

            then
    */
    TaxRate= case when ARTH.TransDate < isnull(#BaseRate.EffectiveDate,'12/31/2070') then (#BaseRate.OldBaseRate)
                   when ARTH.TransDate >= isnull(#BaseRate.EffectiveDate,'12/31/2070') then (#BaseRate.NewBaseRate)
             end,
          ARTL.DiscOffered,
          ARTL.TaxDisc, ARTL.Amount
     --BeginTaxCode=@BeginTaxCode, EndTaxCode=@EndTaxCode, BeginMth=@BeginMth, EndMth=@EndMth
      FROM ARTL with (nolock) 

      Inner Join ARTH  with (nolock) on ARTH.ARCo=ARTL.ARCo and ARTH.Mth=ARTL.Mth and ARTH.ARTrans=ARTL.ARTrans
      Inner Join HQCO  with (nolock) on ARTL.ARCo=HQCO.HQCo
      Inner Join HQTX base  with (nolock) on base.TaxGroup=ARTL.TaxGroup and base.TaxCode=ARTL.TaxCode
      Inner Join #BaseRate  with (nolock) on #BaseRate.TaxGroup=ARTL.TaxGroup and #BaseRate.TaxCode=ARTL.TaxCode
      /*Full outer Join HQTL on HQTL.TaxGroup = ARTL.TaxGroup and HQTL.TaxCode = ARTL.TaxCode
      Full outer Join HQTX local on local.TaxGroup = HQTL.TaxGroup and local.TaxCode = HQTL.TaxLink*/

      WHERE ARTL.ARCo=@ARCo and ARTL.TaxCode>=@BeginTaxCode and ARTL.TaxCode<=@EndTaxCode
      and ARTL.Mth>=@BeginMth and ARTL.Mth<=@EndMth and ARTH.ARTransType Not In ('P','M')

  /* insert Total into #Multilevel */
  insert into #Multilevel
    (ARCo,Name,BaseTaxCode, LocalTaxCode,TaxRate, ARTrans,Mth, Contract, TaxLocalBasisTotal,TaxLocalAmountTotal,
          TaxLocalDiscOffTotal, TaxLocalTaxDiscTotal)

    /*SELECT DISTINCT   ARCo,Name, BaseTaxCode,  LocalTaxCode, TaxRate, ARTrans,Mth, TaxBasis, TaxAmount 
          FROM #Multilevel*/
    Select ARCo, Name, BaseTaxCode, LocalTaxCode, TaxRate, ARTrans, Mth, Contract, sum(TaxBasis), sum(TaxAmount),
    sum(DiscOffered), sum(TaxDisc) 
         From #Multilevel Group By ARCo, Name, BaseTaxCode, LocalTaxCode, Mth, TaxRate, ARTrans, Contract

  insert into #Multilevel
    (ARCo, Name, BaseTaxCode, ARTrans, Mth, TaxBaseBasisTotal, TaxBaseAmountTotal,
          TaxBaseDiscOffTotal, TaxBaseTaxDiscTotal, TotalAmount)
    /*Select Distinct ARCo, Name, BaseTaxCode, ARTrans, Mth, TaxBasis, TaxAmount
    From #Multilevel*/
    Select ARTL.ARCo, HQCO.Name, TaxCode, ARTL.ARTrans, ARTL.Mth, sum(TaxBasis), sum(TaxAmount),
         sum(DiscOffered), sum(TaxDisc), sum(Amount)
    From ARTL  with (nolock) 
    Join ARTH  with (nolock) on ARTH.ARCo=ARTL.ARCo and ARTH.Mth=ARTL.Mth and ARTH.ARTrans=ARTL.ARTrans
    Join HQCO  with (nolock) on HQCO.HQCo=ARTL.ARCo
    WHERE HQCO.HQCo=@ARCo
    and ARTL.ARCo=@ARCo and ARTL.TaxCode between @BeginTaxCode and @EndTaxCode
    and ARTL.Mth between @BeginMth and @EndMth 
    and ARTH.ARCo=@ARCo and ARTH.Mth between @BeginMth and @EndMth 
    and ARTH.ARTransType Not in ('P','M')
    Group By ARTL.ARCo, Name, TaxCode, ARTL.ARTrans, ARTL.Mth


  insert into #Multilevel
    (ARCo, ARTrans, ARLine, Mth,TransDate, AppliedMth, Customer, Invoice, CheckNo, 
         Description, Contract, GLAcct,DiscOffered,TotalAmount,BaseTaxCode, Name)

    Select ARTL.ARCo, ARTL.ARTrans, ARTL.ARLine, ARTL.Mth,ARTH.TransDate, ARTH.AppliedMth, ARTH.Customer, ARTH.Invoice, ARTH.CheckNo, 
        ARTL.Description, ARTH.Contract, ARTL.GLAcct,ARTL.DiscOffered,ARTL.Amount,ARTL.TaxCode, HQCO.Name
    from ARTL with (nolock) 
       Inner Join ARTH  with (nolock) on ARTH.ARCo=ARTL.ARCo and ARTH.Mth=ARTL.Mth and ARTH.ARTrans=ARTL.ARTrans
       Inner Join HQCO with (nolock) on HQCO.HQCo=ARTL.ARCo
    where  @NoTaxLines ='Y' and ARTL.ARCo=@ARCo and ARTL.TaxCode is null
    and ARTL.Mth between @BeginMth and @EndMth  
    and ARTH.ARCo=@ARCo and ARTH.Mth between @BeginMth and @EndMth 
    /*and ARTH.ARTransType Not in ('P','M')*/
  /* REMOVED THE ABOVE SO IT WOULD PULL NEGATIVE/CREDIT AMOUNTS*/



/* Inserting final sales tax data into Multilevel auxiliary table */
insert into #Multilevel_Aux
(Mth, TransDate, AppliedMth, ARTrans, ARLine, Customer, Invoice, Contract, Description, BaseTaxCode, Amount, TaxBasis, TaxAmount)
Select Distinct Mth, TransDate, AppliedMth, ARTrans, ARLine, Customer, Invoice, Contract, Description, BaseTaxCode, Amount, TaxBasis, TaxAmount
from #Multilevel
where ARCo = 1
and Customer is not null and Invoice is not null

/* Setting ANSI_WARNING to OFF in order to prevent SQL Server to throw an exception to Excel which causes Excel not to fetch the data successfully */
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;

/* Updating Multilevel auxiliary table with customer name */
update #Multilevel_Aux
set CustomerName = ARCM.Name 
from ARCM
where ARCM.Customer = #Multilevel_Aux.Customer
```

/* Updating Multilevel auxiliary table with contract name */
    update #Multilevel_Aux
    set ContractName = JCCM.Description 
    from JCCM
    where JCCM.Contract = #Multilevel_Aux.Contract

```
/* Selecting data for the Excel report */
select Mth, TransDate, Customer, CustomerName, Contract, ContractName, Invoice, Description, BaseTaxCode "TaxCode", TaxBasis "Gross", TaxAmount, Amount "Total", AppliedMth, ARTrans, ARLine
from #Multilevel_Aux
```

GO

Comment: just list the columns in the `SELECT` in the order you want them: `SELECT Month, Date, Customer, Contract.....`

Comment: I have already tried that and it does not work.

 select Mth, TransDate, Customer, CustomerName, Contract, ContractName, Invoice, Description, BaseTaxCode "TaxCode", TaxBasis "Gross", TaxAmount, Amount "Total", AppliedMth, ARTrans, ARLine
    from #Multilevel_Aux

Comment: What does "not work" means here?. You should clarify your question, what is your previous result, and what is your desired one

Comment: Even with the select statement provided above, the order remains Month, Date, Applied Month, Customer, Contract, Invoice, Description, Tax Amount, AR Transaction, AR Line, Customer Name, Contract Name, Gross, Total

Comment: That's weird. What SQL are you using? It would also be helpful if you can show us what you tried

Comment: I'm glad someone else thinks it is weird, too. I am pretty new to SQL, so I thought I was just crazy. LOL. SQL Server.

Comment: AS for what I tried, see my first comment on this post. That's the select statement.

Comment: I just added the full code to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up a simple stored procedure with a SELECT statement, and ran it inside Excel.  I then changed the order of the columns in my SELECT statement and ran it again.  I did get the columns to re-order, but the only way I could do it was to delete the original results in Excel, and re-run with a fresh (empty) spreadsheet.  So try these steps:

1. Re-save your stored procedure with the new SELECT statement column order.
2. Delete the old results from your spreadsheet (or go to a new sheet).
3. Check your setup:
   Data tab -> Connections -> Highlight your connection -> Properties -> Definition tab ->        Command Type should be "SQL" and Command Text should be "EXEC [dbo].[udbrptARSalesTax]"
4. Click OK.
5. Click in cell A1.
6. Data -> Get External Data -> highlight your connection -> "Open" -> in the Import Data window, view the data as Table, Existing worksheet, click OK.

The data should then show up in your spreadsheet in the order in which you listed it in your saved stored procedure udbrptARSalesTax.  I was able to change around the columns in my stored procedure SELECT statement, re-generate the procedure, delete the old data in my spreadsheet, then get the external data again from an empty sheet, and the columns were in the new order.

Comment: That's so weird. The only time I can get it to work is in the original workbook but on a new spreadsheet. I get errors on a new workbook. But it's now working. Now I just have to figure out how to add parameters on the excel sheet that will affect the data.